# How to compare two objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i have two  different object with same values
 for example :

```
obj = {name:"John"}
obj 2 = {name :"John"}
```

when i am trying compare both object, **not values** its giving me false

```
obj === obj 2 or obj == obj 2       //i tried both
```

i thought i will return true , but i don't know why it return false even both values are same ;

And when i did this

```
obj 3 = obj
obj 3 === obj
```

it returns me true as output.

help me.
 .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `obj === obj 2 or obj == obj 2 ` is invalid syntax, as is `obj 3 === obj`. Also, with `obj 3 = obj`, `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
var obj = {name:"John"}
var obj2 = {name :"John"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj) == JSON.stringify(obj2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

Comment: will this will work if have numbers too ?

Comment: @PankajJaiswal, yes, this will work for number as well....